# ORA-03114 "нет связи с ORACLE" при попытке открыть объект для правки. Запросы на выборку работают

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsql-developer

Не понимаю в чем дело, понятного объяснения не нашел.
В PL/SQL Developer при попытке открыть процедуру или пакет (пишем имя в SQL окно и кликаем с зажатым Ctrl) падает эта ошибка.

> ORA-03113: принят сигнал конца файла по коммуникационному каналу.
>   Идентификатор процесса: такой-то. Идентификатор сеанса: такой-то.
>   Порядковый номер:такой-то

После нажатия OK выпадает следующая:

> ORA-03114: нет связи с ORACLE

При этом обычные селекты из таблиц продолжают работать. Селекты из представлений так же дают ошибку "нет связи". Например:

```
select * from v$session where username is not null
```

В чем может быть причина и как можно исправить?

Пробовал перезапускать PL/SQL Developer (даже весь комп ребутил). База не локальная, в сети.

Comment: Гугл говорит, что может кончиться место, но сейчас нет возможности подключиться под линуксовым пользователем. Можно как-то оценить это из командной строки оракла?

Comment: [Как посмотреть логи.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49682/ora-03113-end-of-file-on-communication-channel-on-startup)

Comment: @sanmai , спасибо. Я так понимаю, там все-равно нужно зайти на машину с базой?

Comment: Да, это проблема там.

Comment: @sanmai Логи почистил (удалил лишние файлы). Места освободилось гигов двадцать. Но ошибка сохраняется. Причем, её нет если заходить с лягухи или SQL Developer, только в PLSQL Developer. У коллеги с другой машины ситуация аналогичная. Ошибка сохраняется и при установке в соседний каталог 13-й версии.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эта ошибка возникает, если соединение с серверным процессом оборвалось. Самая частая причина - серверный процесс завершился ненормально. Причин этого ненормального завершения может быть очень-очень много и тут без анализа лог-файлов не обойтись.

Узнать, куда серверный процесс пишет логи можно так:

```
SQL> select name, value from v$diag_info;
```

По-умолчанию примерно такое:

```
Default Trace File
$ORACLE_BASE/diag/rdbms/<sid>/<sid>/trace/<sid>_ora_nnnnn.trc
```

Серверный процес обычно не пишет логи (только самые критические ошибки). Включить логгирование можно так:

```
alter session set sql_trace=true;
```

Ошибку как в вопросе я воспроизвести конечно же не могу, но как примерно искать причину подобных ошибок см. далее.

Запускаю сессию с любого клиента и нахожу к нему серверный процесс, в моём случае:

```
oracle   17558     1  0 16:35 ?        00:00:00 oracle<сsid> (LOCAL=NO)
```

Предлагаю ему закрыться (провоцирую ошибку):

```
$ kill -TERM 17558
```

В клиенте получаю ошибку, что  соединения больше нет:

```
SQL> select 1 from dual;
select 1 from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 17558
Session ID: 270 Serial number: 6857
```

В папке trace/, в файле тревог `alert_<sid>.log` нахожу причину:

```
2019-07-26T16:39:53.571956+02:00
PDB1(3):Process termination requested for pid 17558 [source = unknown], [info = -1871706712] 
[request issued by pid: 7532, uid: 1004]
```

Где `pid: 7532, uid: 1004` это оболочка и учётка с которых был выполнен `kill`.