# Отбрасывание не нужного количество строк при соединении трех таблиц с помощью JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Необходимо чтобы получилось одинаковое число записей у обоих выборок,  основываясь на 1 Выборку. 
Версия Oracle 12.1.0.1.0

1 Выборка

```
select count(*) 
from t_pet t, 
     t_block t2 
where t.id=t2.id_ger 
  and trunc(t2.date_end) > '01.01.2000'
```

Есть еще и третья таблица которая также может соединятся по id

2 Выборка

```
select count(*) 
from t_pet t, 
     t_block t2, 
     t_block_outboundmess t3 
where t.id=t2.id_ger 
  and t2.id_ger=t3.id_outletter 
  and trunc(t2.date_end) > '01.01.2000'
```

Comment: *Необходимо чтобы получилось одинаковое число записей у обоих выборок* да не вопрос. Измените данные в `t_block_outboundmess` (удалите лишнее) так, чтобы `id_outletter` было уникальным.

Comment: Данные в t_block_outboundmess нужны, их не нужно удалять

Comment: Какие данные там тебе нужны? ты тупо COUNT() считаешь! И в общем случае получить одинаковый результат в двух показанных запросах - занятие совершенно безнадёжное, ибо в третьей таблице может быть несколько записей с одним и тем же `id_outletter`, а может и не быть ни одной записи с `id_outletter`, равным какому-то из  `t_block.id_ger`. А главное - непонятно, нахрена надо получать равные значения... цели вменяемой не видать - озвучить бы.

Answer (score 3):

Начиная с 12.01 с [CROSS APPLY](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABCHEAJ):

```sql
select count(*) 
from t_pet t 
join t_block t2 on t2.id_ger = t.id 
cross apply (
    select max (id_outletter) keep (dense_rank first order by null) id_outletter
    from t_block_outboundmess t3
    where t3.id_outletter = t2.id_ger) t3
where trunc(t2.date_end) > date'2000-01-01'
```

Если версия 11g и старше, то так:

```sql
select count(*) 
from t_pet t 
join t_block t2 on t2.id_ger = t.id 
join (
    select max (id_outletter) keep (dense_rank first order by null) id_outletter
    from t_block_outboundmess) t3 on t3.id_outletter = t2.id_ger
where trunc(t2.date_end) > date'2000-01-01'
```

На [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f78a50fa44c7698bfed67bfc0630e488).

Comment: Можно с CROSS APPLY

Comment: Можно. Укажите версию в вопросе.

Comment: ORA-03113: принят сигнал конца файла по коммуникационному каналу;
ORA-03114: нет связи с ORACLE

Comment: Ошибки исчезли. Но выборка показывает 0.

Comment: По ORA-03113, смотрите [причину так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1007049/217579).
 У меня тоже 0, т.к. у меня нету данных. Сможете добавить тестовые данные? А старый вариант работает?

Comment: Извиняюсь не внимательно посмотрел. Начиная с 12.01 с CROSS APPLY - также выкидывает ORA-03114 и ORA-03113, а Если версия 11g и старше - показывает 0

Comment: См. комментатрий выше, На [фиддле всё работает](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=eec24bfe7f1d996f40ca839194ebc9ff). Добавляйте туда данные, с которыми у вас не работает, будем смотреть.

Comment: По CROSS APPLY - в 12.01 был баг, насколько помню. Вам надо будет пропатчить базу. См. алертлог, там наверняка ORA-00600.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) 
from t_pet t 
left join t_block t2 on t2.id_ger = t.id 
left join (select * from
(select u.*, row_number() over (partition by id_outletter order by date_response desc)num 
from t_block_outboundmess u) where num=1) t3 on t3.id_outletter = t2.id_ger
where trunc(t2.date_end) > date'2000-01-01'
```

Comment: Несомненно, ваше решение является правильным и решило вашу задачу. Но только оно полностью изменило смысл вопроса. Согласитесь,  о столбце date_response в вопросе вообще не упомяното. И брать  все значения из таблицы  t_block_outboundmess для count(*) нет никакого смысла, то есть вам нужен был всё-таки не  count(*).  Исходя из вышеизложенноого, был интересый вопрос, теперь он стал бесполезным.