# Функция в WITH секции, внутри представления

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

На базе oracle версии 12. Прошу помочь разобраться почему получаю такую экзотичную ошибку как ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel. Хочу создать материализованное представление, внутри которого запрос использует тут же определенную функцию. При этом я не могу использовать запрос внутри этой функции. Ниже упрощенная модель (которая воссоздает ситуацию с ошибкой).

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_test_view
    BUILD IMMEDIATE
    REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND
  AS
WITH
  function test_func(pInput varchar2) return varchar2 as
    v_output varchar2 (1000);
  begin
    if pInput is null then
      return null;
    end if;
    SELECT 'test'
      into v_output
      FROM dual;
  --  v_output := 'test res';
    return v_output;
  exception
    when no_data_found then
      return pInput ;
  end;
SELECT test_func('test val') col_1 FROM dual;
```

При этом, если переместить коммент на запрос из псевдотаблицы, то ошибки не происходит

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_test_view
    BUILD IMMEDIATE
    REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND
  AS
WITH
  function test_func(pInput varchar2) return varchar2 as
    v_output varchar2 (1000);
  begin
    if pInput is null then
      return null;
    end if;
  --  SELECT 'test'
  --    into v_output
  --    FROM dual;
    v_output := 'test res';
    return v_output;
  exception
    when no_data_found then
      return pInput ;
  end;
SELECT test_func('test val') col_1 FROM dual;
```

В чем может быть дело? Есть какие-то ограничения оракла, которые я здесь не учёл?

Comment: Вы же задавали уже [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/999152/217579), там всё вроде хорошо расписанно.

Comment: @0xdb да, мне важно было только услышать, что код правильный, без ошибок. И это не в применении языка проблема как таковом, а конкретно в нашей БД. В англоязычной версии гражданин прогнал скрипт и подтвердил, что он рабочий. К сожалению, к логам доступа нет, админов тоже не допросишься. Придется с помощью ломика и такой-то матери обходное решение колхозить. А за тот ответ тоже спасибо, очень подробный ответ, да.

Comment: Да, к тому ответу можно добавить, что если встретится опять эта ошибка, то как запрос или скрипт написан - правильно или неправильно, красиво  или нет, не играет абсолютно никакой роли. Они просто "провокаторы" ошибки, но ошибка не в них.